# how to split a string in two strings in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

I have a `string` with a lot of characters. I would like to split the `string` into 2 sub-strings. I don't need to use `getfirsthalf()` and `getsecondhalf()`, but that is the idea of what i need to achieve.

```
var compleet = "This is the string with a lot of characters";

var part1 = compleet.getFirstHalf();
var part2 = compleet.getSecondHalf()

//output 
var part1 = "This is the string wi";
var part2 = "th a lot of characters";
```

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: What defines 'half' of a string?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown What if the string has 7 characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**substring()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) with the `length` of the string to divide the string in two parts by using the index.

> The substring() method returns a subset of a string between one index and another, or through the end of the string.

```js
var compleet = "This is the string with a lot of characters";
var len = compleet.length;


var firstHalf = compleet.substring(0, len / 2);
var secondHalf = compleet.substring(len / 2);

document.write(firstHalf);
document.write('<br />');
document.write(secondHalf);
```

You can also use [**substr()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

Answer (score 2):

You must to be more specific in your questions. But here you are a simply solution:

```
var str = "an string so long with the characters you need";
var strLength = str.length;
console.log(str.substring(0 , (strLength / 2));
console.log(str.substring((strLength / 2));
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that when you say 'half' a string, you actually mean that two separate strings are returned containing half of the original string's characters each, you could write a prototype function to handle that as follows:

```
String.prototype.splitInHalf = function()
{
    var len = this.length,
        first = Math.ceil( len / 2 );

    return [
        this.substring(0, first),
        this.substring(first)
    ];
}
```

When called as `compleet.splitInHalf()`, This function will return an array containing the two halves, as follows:

```
["This is the string wit", "h a lot of characters"]
```

Since we use `Math.ceil()` here, the prototype will also favour the first half of the string. For example, given a string that has an odd number of characters, such as `This is`, the returned array will contain 4 characters in the first string, and 3 in the second, as follows:

```
["This", " is"]
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/h32xvwvb/)